# Converting hour extraction to Bigquery standardSQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am converting query from Snowflake to Bigquery:

```
date_part(hour, convert_timezone('UTC', 'US/Eastern', to_timestamp(to_numeric((FLOOR(start_ts)))))) in (6,7,8,9)
```

start_ts is of the format: 1563026408.17193
and is a float.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TIMESTAMP_MILLIS()` to convert the value to a timestamp.  Then convert to a `DATETIME`:

```
select DATETIME(timestamp_MICROS(cast(1563026408.17193 * 1000000 as int64)), 'America/New_York')
```

Instead of `datepart()`, use `extract(hour . . .)` to extract the hour.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent expression for BigQuery Standard SQL will be

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(CAST(1000000 * start_ts AS INT64)), 'US/Eastern')) IN (6,7,8,9)
```